# ¿Porque me puede decir que error '$' no está definido?

Tags: firebase, vue.js

```
Editar(piloto){
      $('#Editar').modal('show');

  this.piloto = piloto.data();
  this.activeItem = piloto.id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te falta incluir la librería `jQuery`.
El selector del tipo `$('#Editar')` es el selector de `jQuery`.